# MySQL id numbering in table

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say that I have a table linked to a database like this: http://www.falkencreative.com/forum/records/view.php

How do I make it so that when I delete a record and then add a new one, the new replaces the previously deleted record and has the previously deleted id number instead of the next id?

For example

1. Red
2. Blue
3. Green

click button to delete green.

1. Red
2. Blue

click button to add new color.
input orange

1. Red
2. Blue
3. Orange

As it stands, what I'm working with is putting out:
1. Red
2. Blue
4. Orange (What should set this to 3?)

It's probably something simple in terms of the table set up, but I have no idea what to do and I'm pressed for time. Can anyone guide me on what I should do?

Comment: I just realized that you are separating the delete and insert into two separate actions.  Why do you want to reuse IDs?

Comment: Hi Brian,

I have an HTML page that takes input values and places them into the table or create.

Then I have the edit and delete function on the sides, like so in the link.

I was asked to make the database flow in sequential order. I have no objections if this is not the most efficient way, but it was what I was instructed to do. I guess it shows neatness, I'm not certain—I'm just trying to do what I was asked.

Answer (score 1):

You may have 2 options. Either update the same row where the "Green" value was previously. i.e.:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET color = 'orange' WHERE ID = '3'");
```

or

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET color = 'orange' WHERE color = 'green'");
```

or

whatever your specifiers could be.

this should be from the MySql standpoint the easiest way. Or you can delete it as you initially outlined and re insert new row with mysql_query("INSERT INTO .... but then MySql PK UID will need to be reset i.e.:

```
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
```

which will remove your used PK IDs and renumbers all rows.  Or is there an easier solution ?

Comment: Thank you for the insight and time.

But I'm partially confused with the first two queries or how to use them, since I have multiple things in the row such as dropdown inputs etc..

The third, I understand a little more. Is this going to help me to echo out everything in order? At this point I want to echo out the entries in order because when I delete one and then add new, everything is goobledigook and id's are everywhere after that edit/delete point.

Comment: ok... could you send me the exact table column headers and I will try to make it more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to UPDATE the record, rather than DELETE the old and INSERT a new one.

**Edit:**

If you want to insert a new record and assign it the next sequential id, use a non-auto_increment column and do this when adding a new record:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (id, ...) VALUES ( (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM myTable), ...)
```

I don't have a database handy to test this, but I think it will work.  But I'm not sure what will happen when the table is empty. Also this may create a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

No, when you delete a database row, if the column have the `AUTO_INCREMENT` active, it will take the value from a sequence.
If you delete 3, the sequence always start from 3+1.
You can see\set the auto-increment value for example from php myadmin. 
I don't know what DBMS are you using, but with oracle you can manipulate the sequence.

So you have various way.

1. Complicated: When you insert\delete you update the sequence with the triggers
2. You use 3 coloumn: `id`, `IdToShow`, `Value`.

`id` is the same of now, you use it with autoinc.
`idToShow` also is what you show. When you insert you can insert it counting the rows present in the table (you have various ways).

Hope it help.

Comment: I'm sorry with admins, I'm not still very practical with code when I write an answer. Next time I'll be more carefully.

Comment: Hi Andrea, I am using PHPmyadmin, yes.

So are you saying that there is a way to have an id in the database that auto increments but a way to reflect it onto the page as if I wanted 1,2,3 and not 1,2,4(though it appears this way in the database?)

Comment: Yes you can use different coloumn for id and the id you whant show and the id you see in the db. When you insert the coloumn you want show (the 1,2,3 ecc) you count the rows present in table.

Comment: (sorry for the multiple edit but when I press enter it public directly)
 When you insert the coloumn you want show (the 1,2,3,4 ecc) you count the rows present in table while the id (primary key) of the row is for example 1,2,5,6.
If you must insert the fourt value but you have deleted a row before, the coloumn for the primary key will take value from the auto inc (so n+1 ergo 4+1), while the row to show will count the effective rows in the table (so if you will count m rows, you will insert m+1)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not about database IDs, it's about not understanding the difference between an ID and a line number. They have nothing to do with each other. Just simply output the loop counter ("$i") instead of the ID.

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= foo(); $i++) {
    print "<tr><td>{$i}</td><td>...</td></tr>\n";
}
?>
```